# Cannot get REST API usage records examples to work

Tags: ruby

I'm using the following example given in the api docs for twilio-ruby.

http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/usage-records#list-get-example-3

```
# twilio-ruby install docs at twilio.com/docs/ruby/install
require 'rubygems'          # This line not needed for ruby > 1.8
require 'twilio-ruby'

# Get your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account 
account_sid = 'AC32a3c49700934481addd5ce1659f04d2'
auth_token = '{{ auth_token }}'
@client = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token

# Loop over records and print out a property for each one
@client.account.usage.records.list({
  :category => "calls-inbound",
  :start_date => "2012-09-01",
  :end_date => "2012-09-30"}).each do |record|
  puts record.sid
end
```

(I am swapping out the proper credentials, and have set dates to those where I have inbound calls).

I am getting

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `sid' for #<Twilio::REST::Record:0x007f8f2c94c948>
```

If I remove the call to .sid and inspect the response I get the following

```
[<Twilio::REST::Record @uri=/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Usage/Records/>]
```

So basically an array with one member with a uri property.

So. why is the initial example not working and what can I do with the response if not call .sid on it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API documentation is wrong on the site.

```
# twilio-ruby install docs at twilio.com/docs/ruby/install
require 'rubygems'          # This line not needed for ruby > 1.8
require 'twilio-ruby'

# Get your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account 
account_sid = 'AC32a3c49700934481addd5ce1659f04d2'
auth_token = '{{ auth_token }}'
@client = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token


# Loop over records and print out a property for each one
@client.account.usage.records.today.list.each do |record|
    puts record.category + ' : ' + record.usage
end
```

For reference: https://github.com/twilio/twilio-ruby/issues/52